# How to animate zIndex transition with anime.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, velocity.js

I'm trying to do zIndex transition using [anime.js](http://anime-js.com/):

I have a div with following css rule applied:

```
div {
  background: #1CE2B2;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I want to animate zIndex transition of the div:

```
$(document).click(() => {
  var keyframes = anime({
    targets: 'div',
    zIndex: [
      { value: '50', duration: 500, },
      { value: '100', duration: 500, },
      { value: '150', duration: 500, },
    ],
  });
})
```

but zIndex changes from 1 to 150 without intermediate values 50 and 100. What am I missing?

Is it possible with velocity.js or jQuery?

<strike>Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/evgeny_t/pen/BRNKZe</strike>

How it was filled on github: https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/156

**UPD**

The code above should be changed to:

```
$(document).click(() => {
  var keyframes = anime({
    targets: 'div',
    zIndex: [
      { value: '50', duration: 500, round:true },
      { value: '100', duration: 500, round:true },
      { value: '150', duration: 500, round:true },
    ],
  });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-index property doesn't accept decimals, that's why it jumps directly to 5.
Try rounding the value, like this :

```
anime({
  targets: '.box',
  rotate: [45, 45],
  scale: [0, 5],
  zIndex: {
    value: [1, 5],
    round: true
  },
  loop: true,
  duration: 10000,
});
```